# Не показывается окно

Tags: python, tkinter

Помогите пожалуйста с программой, не могу понять почему не запускается окно, хоть в редакторе и не выдает ошибок.

```
from tkinter import *
import requests
from tkinter import messagebox, ttk
from tkinter.ttk import Progressbar
import flask
import time

tk = Tk()


def procstart():
    lone.configure(text="func started...")
    messagebox.showinfo('Sucsessful!', 'Func started')
    alphabet = ("1234567890qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm")
    base = len(alphabet)

    length = 0
    counter = 0
    while True:
        password = ""

        temp = counter
        while temp > 0:
            rest = temp % base
            temp = temp // base
            password = alphabet[rest] + password
        while len(password) < length:
            password = alphabet[0] + password

        print(password)
        response = requests.post(txt_one.get(), json={'login': txt.get(), 'password': password})

        resp = int(response.status_code)
        if resp == 200:
            print(password)
        break

        if password == alphabet[-1] * length:
            length += 1
            counter = 0
        else:
            counter += 1


for i in range(100):
    pbar = 0
    time.sleep(60)
    pbar += 1
tk.title('IntHack by XDie')
tk.geometry('640x480')
lone = Label(tk, text='Input login: ', font=('Times', 22))
lone.grid(column=1, row=0)
btn = Button(tk, text="Start!", bg="Black", fg="Red", command=procstart)
btn.grid(column=3, row=1)
label = Label(tk, text="processes:")
label.grid(column=0, row=10)
lbl = Label(tk, text=password)
lbl.grid(column=1, row=11)
txt = Entry(tk, width=14)
txt.grid(column=0, row=0)
lbl_one = Label(tk, text="Select site: ")
lbl_one.grid(column=0, row=5)
txt_one = Entry(tk, width=14)
txt_one.grid(column=0,row=6)
style = ttk.Style()
style.theme_use('default')
style.configure("black.Horizontal.TProgressbar", background='black')
bar = Progressbar(tk, length=200, style='black.Horizontal.TProgressbar')
bar['value'] = pbar
bar.grid(column=0, row=3)
response = requests.get(site)
tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Ваш цикл for очень долгий.. до его завершения ничего не отобразится.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

зачем нужен этот участок кода

```
for i in range(100):
    pbar = 0
    time.sleep(60)
    pbar += 1
```

данный участок будет выполняться один час и сорок минут